# Using regular LINUX password for mapping (mounting) LINUX directory to the MS windows

Tags: linux, windows, samba

How can I configure samba so that users can map their home directory on a linux server to the local MS Windows machine (so called network drive mapping), by using their linux account and their regular linux password for that account. I other words, I do not want to create Samba users and their associated Samba passwords

Answer (score 0):

I've learned (and confirmed with few tests) that 'samba' can not work directly with the user names and associated passwords from linux account. The 'samba' needs to have its own user list and associated passwords. However, I also learned that 'samba' can automagically change linux password file when the samba's password is changed by user. See **Password Synchronization** on [this page](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html).